# Replacing text in set of files, and writing to new files

Tags: python

I have a set of .SQL scripts in a folder (maybe 20 or so files).  I want to search every file in that folder and replace 'ABC' with 'ABCD' and 'XYZ' with 'WXYZ', and then take each file that's been processed and save it in a different folder (path_2) in example below, with the same file name as the original.

I know this is not working, what tweaks are needed?

```
import sys 

def main():

path = "C:/path/to/input/folder"
path_2 = "C:/path/to/input/folder"



def replace_text(replacements):

    replacements = {'ABC': 'ABCD', 'XYZ':'WXYZ'}
    path_2.write()


for filename in path:
    if filename.endswith('.sql') 
    open(filename,'r')
    replace_text()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `path` and `path_2` are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many syntax errors in your code. @Hugh-Bothwell pointed out those errors. Also, both paths are same.

If you want to do just these two replacements, I think there is no need to create a separate function or a dictionary.

Following code should work -

```
import os

def main():

    path = "C:/path/to/input/folder"
    path_2 = "C:/path/to/output/folder"

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if filename.endswith('.sql'):
            #Getting Full file paths to read/write
            full_file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
            new_file_path = os.path.join(path_2, filename)

            with open(full_file_path,"r") as f:
                content = f.read()
                content = content.replace("ABC","ABCD").replace("XYZ","WXYZ")

                '''This will save all the files to new location, even if there is no change, to save only changed files, 
                    copy the content to a temp variable and check if there is any change before saving''' 
                with open(new_file_path, "w") as f_new:
                    f_new.write(content)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Note:**

- The path to the new location should exist, or you can create the
  path   using - `os.makedirs(path_2)`
- The replacements are case sensitive
- It will replace the occurrences in between the words too, e.g `MNABCS` will be replaced by `MNABCDS`

Comment: you guys are great.  Thank you both

Comment: the code worked perfectly, thank you.  Just for curiousity sake, what if  I had to replace many more text strings (other than just 2)?  Would you recommend another approach other than hard-coding the values like you did?  Is that where a function/method would come into play?

Comment: @JD2775 You can use the above code for any number of changes, but to improve readability and ease in modifying changes later you can create a dictionary of changes, then iterate through that dict and make the changes. It will be a little slower though.

Answer (score 2):

- you never actually get `filename` - you could use `os.listdir()`, or `glob.glob("*.sql")` might be easier
- `if filename.endswith('.sql')` needs to end with a colon
- below that, `open` and `replace_text` need to be indented
- the contents of `main` need to be indented
- `def replace_text` should not be in `main`
- you `open` the file; you should then `.read()` the contents and pass it to `replace_text`
- `replace_text` doesn't do anything; for each `key,value` pair in `replacements.items()` you should do `text.replace(key, value)`
- `replace_text` should then pass the updated text back to `main`
- `main` should then save the updated text